# Does the partial derivative w.r.t $x$ and $y$ exist at $x, y = 0$ for the following function $f$?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

Does the partial derivative w.r.t $x$, $y$ exist at $x=0$ and $y=0$ for the function $f(x, y)$=$\frac{x^3y^2}{x^6 +y^2}$ (when$(x, y) \neq0$} and $f(0,0)=0$)

If we go by the definition, then I think numerator is surely going to be zero but the denominator is near to zero but not exactly zero. So I think the partial derivative w.r.t $x$ should exist. Please help me to clear my doubt. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean $$\frac{x^3 y^2}{x^6 + y^2}$$ or $$y^2(x^{-3}+1)$$?

Comment: I meant the first one $(x^3y^2) /(x^6+y^2)$

Comment: Put in your edition for a fraction the following way: first $ followed of \ and put { and } instead of ( and ).

Comment: One way to find out the answer you want to find is as follow: graph the flat curve $\dfrac{x^3y^2}{x^6+y^2} = a$ for various values of $a$ (you will easily see that point (0,0) has in common "something" that will call you attention).

Comment: Thanks I am working in this way, and in question I want to make it more precise by adding function $\frac{x^3y^2}{x^6+y^2}$ is for $x,y \neq0$, for$(x, y) =0$ function equals to zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $$\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x-0}$$
first you have to calculate $f(x,0)-f(0,0)$ :
$$f(x,0)-f(0,0)=0,$$
then you have $$\frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x-0}=0 \quad (x \not =0)$$
so $$\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x-0}=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

The def'n of $\partial f(x,y)/\partial x$ at $(a,b)$ is $\lim_{x\to a}\frac {f(x,b)-f(a,b)}{x-a}.$

For the $f$ of the Q this is $0$ when $b=0$ because $f(x,0)=f(a,0)=0$ for any $x$ and any $a.$